# How to detect Location Provider ? GPS or Network Provider

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I'm using [Fused Location Provider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) for location updates in my app. According to Fused Location Provided documentation, it uses all available resources (e.g. Wifi, GPS, Cell tower, etc..) to optimize location.

But i want to know, is there any way to detect that current location update is from GPS Provider or Network provider, in Location update receiver ?

Comment: what you have read about fused location provider can you provide any documentation ,please

Comment: I've read these links : http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/05/16/inside-googles-new-location-apis-for-android/ and
http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check the location provider by `location.getProvider()` from the location you are getting.

Either you are using fused location api or a previous one, you will get the location from `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation` or `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` and from location you can get provider by `location.getProvider`

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: see either you are using fused location api or previous one you will location from locationManager.getLastKnownLocation or LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation and from location you can get provider by location.getProvider

Answer (score 0):

Just few month before **Google** release the New and simple api for location listener.

It's simple with a few lines of code .

Let me explain

Step 1:Download Google play Service library using SDK manager.Because Location service connect to the Google play.

Step 2: Import library into your work space

Step 3: Add library into your project

step 4: write the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LocationClient mlocationclient;

    Location location;

    LocationRequest mlocationrequest;

    int trasition_type=Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER;

    LocationListener mlistener;

    PendingIntent lviolation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int isGooglePlayServiceAvilable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (isGooglePlayServiceAvilable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        //Create the location client
        mlocationclient=new LocationClient(getApplicationContext(),  new CallBack(), new ConnectError());

        mlocationclient.connect();



        //create the location request objetcs..
        mlocationrequest=LocationRequest.create().setInterval(1000).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);




        //Crearte the location listener when we want to get location.
        mlistener=new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Log.i("Mine Location", ""+location);

            }
        };

        public class ConnectError implements GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
        {


            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        }

        public class CallBack implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks
        {



            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                location=mlocationclient.getLastLocation();

                mlocationclient.requestLocationUpdates(mlocationrequest, mlistener);

                //new GetAddress(getApplicationContext()).execute(location);



            }


        }
```

Step 5: Put this code in android manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` 


 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I'm using this library, it is Fused Location library about which i'm talking.

Comment: If you working on the Fused Location Provider which are documented in developer site,same things I had discuss above.Its Google play jar file bring to our application.because location service getting through the Google play API.