# GPS Listner LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER causes ANR

Tags: java, android, service, gps

A have a problem with GPS Listner. When I use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER application application work few sec fine and then starts not responding (ANR). When I use only LocationManager.NETWORK, evrything working fine. I have needed permision and lines in AndroidManifes.xml (I think so). This my code:

BackgroundGPSService.java

```
public class BackgroundGPSService extends Service implements GPSLocationListner {
    private GPSService service;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public BackgroundGPSService getService() {
            return BackgroundGPSService.this;
        }
    }

    private final IBinder localBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return localBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        service = new GPSService(this);
        service.construct();
        service.setGPSLocationListner(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        service.destory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateSetteliteCount(int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFirstFix() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdate(double lat, double lon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This is my GPSService which implements GpsStatus.Listener.

GPSService.java

```
public class GPSService implements GpsStatus.Listener {
    private Context context;

    private FineLocationListner fineListner;

    private GPSLocationListner listner;

    private GPSInfoStruct gpsInfo = new GPSInfoStruct();

    public GPSService(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void construct() {
        LocationManager locationManager = getLocationManager();

        fineListner = new FineLocationListner();
        coarseListner = new CoarseLocationListner();

        List<String> providerList = (ArrayList<String>)locationManager.getAllProviders();
        for(int i=0; i<providerList.size(); i++) {
            String providerName = providerList.get(i);
            if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "PROVIDERS LIST name: " + providerName + " enable: " + locationManager.isProviderEnabled(providerName));
            if(providerName.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, fineListner);
            Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerList.get(i));
            gpsInfo.updateLocation(loc);
        }

        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return gpsInfo.getLocation();
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return gpsInfo.getLatitude();
    }

    public double getLon() {
        return gpsInfo.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        if(event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS) {
            GpsStatus status = getLocationManager().getGpsStatus(null);
            int counter = 0;
            Iterable<GpsSatellite> satellites = status.getSatellites();
            Iterator<GpsSatellite> satIter = satellites.iterator();
            while(satIter.hasNext()) {
                counter++;
            }

            //if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "THIS onGpsStatusChanged: " + event + " cnt: " + counter);

            gpsInfo.setSetteliteCount(counter);
            if(listner != null)
                listner.onUpdateSetteliteCount(counter);

        } else if(event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX) {
            if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "THIS onFirstFix");
            gpsInfo.setFix();
            if(listner != null)
                listner.onFirstFix();
        } else
            if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "THIS onGpsStatusChanged: " + event);
    }

    public void setGPSLocationListner(GPSLocationListner listner) {
        this.listner = listner;
        if(gpsInfo.isFix()) listner.onFirstFix();
        listner.onUpdateSetteliteCount(gpsInfo.getSetteliteCount());
        listner.onLocationUpdate(gpsInfo.getLatitude(), gpsInfo.getLongitude());
    }

    public void destory() {
        getLocationManager().removeUpdates(fineListner);
        getLocationManager().removeUpdates(coarseListner);
        getLocationManager().removeGpsStatusListener(this);
    }

    private LocationManager getLocationManager() {
        return (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    class FineLocationListner implements LocationListener {
            ///implementation
}
```

And in LoginActuivity I start service

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundGPSService.class));
    }
}
```

Something i'm missing?

EDIT 1

When I commnet this line:

```
locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
```

Application work fine. I think ther is a problem, but why? :(

Comment: what message exactly you have got please post logcat error

Comment: I dont't have any error in logcat. My application just don't response and then show ANR dialog box. http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2009_files/jnbJan2009-anr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Android release new Location API.Its pretty easy and writing few line of code you will get the location

I have already posted answer please go this link.

[How to detect Location Provider ? GPS or Network Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350665/how-to-detect-location-provider-gps-or-network-provider/20352181#20352181)

Comment: It's not a answer for my question, but it's resolve my problem. Thanks a lot.