# Android 4.0.4: requestSingleLocationUpdate does not work

Tags: java, android, gps, location, tracking

I have the following code:

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements LocationListener {
  [...]

public static class TrackingStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, TrackingService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}

  [...]

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    [...]
    LocationManager locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locmgr.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, this, null);
    locmgr.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
    [...]
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("AppTag", "Reporting a location");
    reportNewLocation(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getProvider(), location.getAccuracy(), location.getSpeed(), location.getTime());
  }
[...]
}
```

It gets started through a system broadcast (BOOT_COMPLETED or MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED or MY_PACKAGE_ADDED) what works according to logcat outputs.

My problem is that a  location is never reported. I also tried Looper.myLooper()...
Can anyone direct me what I am doing wrong?

I logcat I can see some debug output from onStartCommand and I can see it runs through completely through that method. But the recevier gets never called? (I waited about 10 Minutes)

Comment: Answer is already posted.Please have  look @ this

[How to detect Location Provider ? GPS or Network Provider][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350665/how-to-detect-location-provider-gps-or-network-provider/20352181#20352181

Comment: I am sorry but this does not use requestSingleLocationUpdate but uses Google Play Service SDK which is not an option as it has to be able to run on any android phone wven if google play si not available